# ActiveRecord Query of associated model Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have three models in rails, Project(date, has_many :project_savings), Usage(month, amount, has_many :project_savings) and MonthlyProjectSaving(amount, belongs_to :usages, :projects).

It's set up so that each project has a number of savings which correspond to a number of usages months. I'm trying to find all the project savings which have a corresponding `project.date` >= `usage.month`, and also a `usage.amount == 0` in the most secure way possible. `usage.month` and `project.date` are both date types.

Below is basically what I'm trying to get, but I've tried a number of ways and can't get the syntax right.

In my project show view:

```
s = @project.monthly_project_savings
s.where(s.usage.month >= @project.date).where(s.amount: 0)
```

I'd prefer a solution which doesn't leave it open to SQL injections. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this, but I'm not sure what `monthly_project_savings` is, or what types Usage#month and Project#date are.

```
s.joins(:usages).where('usages.month >= ?', @project.date).where(amount: 0)
```

Using `.where` with placeholders in strings is perfectly fine, since the arguments are automatically quoted appropriately. It's direct SQL modification or interpolation with untrusted parameters that you should avoid. More information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Short aside: doing queries in a view isn't very MVC; it be better to do it in the controller or, even better, in a model.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for! Whoops, I was a bit unclear and had a typo in the question (fixed now). Yeah I've been trying to think of ways to get it out of the view and into the model, that's the next challenge I suppose! Cheers.